# Logical consistency of a probability measure on ($\Omega, F$)

Tags: probability, measure-theory

Suppose we have some $\Omega$ and $F$ which is a sigma algebra on $\Omega$.

My questions revolves around if we define a measure $\mu$ on $(\Omega, F)$, then can we always find another measure $\mu'$ such that $\mu'(\{\omega\})$ is defined $\forall \omega \in \Omega$ and $\mu(A_i) = \sum_{\omega_j \in A_i} \mu'(\{\omega_j\}) \forall A_i \in F$?

My question arises from the fact that $F$ does not always contain singleton sets, for example, in dice outcomes, $\{\{1,2,3\}, \{4,5,6\}, \Omega, \emptyset\}$ could be such an $F$. In this case, we can find probabilities to assign to $\{1\}, \{2\}, ...$ in a way consistent with our earlier measure.

However, I don't know how to show/disprove the existence of a counterexample where I can have a valid sigma algebra on $\Omega$ and a valid measure, but I cannot find an induced measure which assigns measure to the singleton elements and is consistent with the earlier constructed measure. Could someone let me know where I can find information on such a counterexample or proof that it doesn't exist? If you could also share the rough intuition behind it it would be highly appreciated!

If there do exist counterexamples, what about in the finite case where $|\Omega| < \infty$?

Comment: Your definition of measure is wrong.

Comment: @geetha290krm thanks, I've fixed the definition. Could you please take another look please? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

For a counterexample, consider the Borel measure $\mu$ on $[0,1]$, which is a probability measure. In particular, for all $x \in [0,1]$, $\mu(\{x\})=0$, while  $\mu([0,1])= 1$.

The hypothesized measure $\mu'$ is required to agree with $\mu$ whenever $\mu$ is defined. Thus it would satisfy
$$1 = \mu([0,1]) = \sum_{x\in [0,1]}\mu'(\{x\}) = \sum_{x\in [0,1]}\mu(\{x\})= 0$$ which is impossible.

The basic difficulty is that probability measures are only required to satisfy *countable* additivity.